# Split Dataframs into its Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing the code I have 461 columns in my dataset and I don't know the **names of that column** so I need to split those columns

> i.e **[0,1,2,3,4,.......,461] columns**

I want to split into 2 data sets

> i.e **X = [0,1,2,3,4,......,460]** and **Y = [461]**

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
dataset.head()
X = dataset.iloc[0:460]
#or 
X = dataset.filter(dataset[:460] , axis=1)
Y = dataset.iloc[:-1]
```

Comment: what's wrong with `X, Y = df.iloc[:, :-1], df.iloc[:, -1:]`?

Answer (score 0):

You could read the whole dataset as X and then just `pop` one column and assign it to Y. `pop` does remove the column from the df and at the same time it returns the popped column.

```
import pandas as pd
X = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
Y = X.pop(X.columns[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv(r'Drive:\\path\\file.csv')
# Select all but last column
split = X[X.columns[:460]]
# Select last column
last_col= X[X.columns[-1:]]
```